# Maven running testNG suite twice

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I have a Selenium-Java-TestNG-Maven suite. I am running this through pom xml. But maven is running the tests in testng xml twice. but when I ran the same TestNG xml as testNG suite then it is behaving normally i.e. it is running the tests in TestNG xml only once as expected.

`
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    Auto
    Auto
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    
        src
        
            
                src
                
                    **/*.java
                
            
        
        
            
                maven-compiler-plugin
                3.7.0
                
                    1.8
                    1.8
                
            
            
                org.apache.maven.plugins
                maven-surefire-plugin
                3.0.0-M3
                
                    
                    
                        testng.xml
                        testng.xml
                    
                    never</forkMode> -->
                    false

```
</build>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

show us the  section. It may be a cause of the problem

Comment: I have added below the build section of the pom xml.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I had included testng.xml twice. Solved it. I had included testng.xml twice. Also set the testNG scope to Compile in my testng xml

Comment: You should accept your answer, so that the question gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

```html
I was also facing with maven project - TestNG Framework - Maven Test was running twice  
Reason - In Pom.xml File I have included testng.xml details twice .ex
    Tag1 suitexmlFile     testng.xml  
    Tag2 suitexmlFile     C:\Selenium\lmsmaven\testng.xml
Once you remove one testng.xml details to
Tag1 suitexmlFile     C:\Selenium\lmsmaven\testng.xml
It will work
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your answer.